# In Python, I am having trouble finding out if an item is in a list

Tags: python, list, search, nested

I am trying to search nested lists for items. The lists will have a mixture of strings and numbers...which don't have to be integers I suppose. Separate from the program I am trying to write, I made a small set of code just to play around with searching lists, but nothing seems to work. I am new to this so be easy on me. I appreciate any direction here.
The contents of the list print, and the variable for the user input section does set appropriately. However, I am getting "False" when I would expect "True", and my 'if' statements that try to see if the item exists keeps telling me that it does not.

Here is the code of my test file:

```
test_list=[['a','b','c',1,2,3],['d','e','f',4,5,6]]

print('contents of the list:')
print (test_list)

print('Checking if "a" is in the list:')
if ('a' in test_list)==True:
    print('yes its in the list')
else:
    print('no it is not in the list')
print('')

print('will this return True?:')
print('a' in test_list)


# trying a user entered value, which
# is directly related to what I want to do
print('now for a user entered value:')
item=input ('enter-->')
if ((item) in test_list)==True:
    print('yes its in the list')
else:
    print('no it is not in the list')
print('')

# shows the user's entry, to show that at least
# the 'item' variable had been set to the value.
# This does show the value entered.
print('The entered number was',item)
print ((item) in test_list)
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `False` for `if item in test_list` because `test_list` is a list of lists, and you are only searching the first "level". Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to search nested lists:

```
if [item in sublist for sublist in test_list]:
    print("Found!")
```

Also, keep in mind that [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) always returns a `str`, so you won't be able to search your numeric list members unless you cast it to an `int`, or turn all the list items into strings.

Comment: Note that `input` always returns a string, so after fixing as above, you still need to make all of the integers in `test_list` into strings.

Comment: Thanks! I am playing with my test code for now with your suggestions in mind!

Answer (score 1):

For a recursive search "in depth" (not only at the first level) you can use a recursive function like this:

```py
def search_recursive(el, l):
    if el in l:
        return True
    for e in l:
        if type(e) == list:
            return search_recursive(el, e)
    return False
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, that will  help with some aspects that I am facing for sure!